# How to add Legend in highchart compare stock chart

Tags: highcharts

I want to use http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare but it doesnt show any legends. But the legends can be seen in http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic.

How to implement legends for http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare ?

Answer (score 4):

Simply add

```
legend: {
    enabled: true
}
```

Note: Answering my own :)

Answer (score 4):

you can use

```
legend: {
enabled: true
}
```

[See working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/aec59xty/)